# How to get a reference to all elements projected in Component?

Tags: angular

What should I do if I want to get a reference to all elements projected in my Component?

Let's say I have `AppComponent` which projects some links and images into `TestComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
class TestComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <test>
      <img src="http://example.org/1.jpg">
      <a href="http://example.org">Some Link</a>
    </test>
  `,
  directives: [ TestComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Now how can I get a reference to those links and images (and potentially other element types) inside my `TestComponent` ?

Reading [this post](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) suggests the following:

> Solution: ContentChildren + directive with li selector
>
> One great solution is to take advantage of the selector in the
>   @Directive decorator. You simply define a directive that selects for
>   <li> elements, then use a @ContentChildren query to filter all <li>
>   elements down to only those that are content children of the
>   component.

But this only works if I want to get a single element type, but if I want to get more than one type that means I have to create a directive for each type I want (and what if I want all types?)...this doesn't feel like a practical method.

Is there another way? or is direct DOM manipulation the only solution in this case?

Comment: You can use one directive with the desired selectors like this `@Directive({ selector: 'a, img' })`

Comment: @yurzui oh, I tried that with the global selector `*` but it didn't work so I thought listing multiple selectors would not work also. Feel free to add an answer and I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using multiple selectors on the directive like this:

```typescript
@Directive({ selector: 'a, img' })
```

Angular only allows directives to trigger on CSS selectors that do not cross element boundaries. So `selector` may be declared as one of the following:

- `element-name`: select by element name.
- `.class`: select by class name.
- `[attribute]`: select by attribute name.
- `[attribute=value]`: select by attribute name and value.
- `:not(sub_selector)`: select only if the element does not match the `sub_selector`.
- `selector1, selector2`: select if either `selector1` or `selector2` matches.

Comment: list of declaration +1 :)

Comment: Okay... we have test component - how wil lthe whole solutin look like with this directive in the test component where the content is projected ??? How can we access the value of the `a` tag ?